# How to assign IDs to each radio button in drupal form radios?

Tags: theming, forms

I am using drupal form radios, I can use Prefix and Suffix to assign IDs to group, how can I assign different IDs to each radio button inside the radios element? Thanks

Comment: Use tags to indicate drupal version. And when refering to form elements, use their formal type in unambigious way. '#type' => 'radios', right? Not just many single '#type'=>'radio'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [theme_radios()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radios/7) hook in your template.php file, if what you get is insufficient.

> **Parameters**
>
> $variables: An associative array containing:
>
> - element: An associative array containing the properties of the element. Properties used: #title, #value, #options, #description, #required, #attributes, #children.
>
> **Return value**
>
> A themed HTML string representing the radio button set.

To interfere with single radio element, see [theme_radio()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radio/7), of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for giving extra IDs for your radio buttons.

Comment: Is it not possible through drupal? I want to implement the drupal way.

Comment: I think Drupal itself gives IDs to all the radio buttons you have on the page. You only need to inspect it properly.

Comment: No, drupal does not give IDs to each radio inside #type=>radios, that's why I asked it.

Comment: @Ankur - "Drupal" does not give IDs. Theme can give them. Or not. If rashidkhan can't see them, it's well possible theme he is using does not add them.

Comment: @Ankur  Can you expand a little on how the OP can use jQuery to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Display Suite module might be what you're looking for:

http://drupal.org/project/ds

Display Suite lets you create your own id's and classes, and then assign them to your form fields, either keeping Drupal's default and adding your new ones, or it can completely replace the existing id's and classes with your new ones. Here's a screen shot of a radio button field I have on a form I recently created: http://www.territorialnetworks.com/design-suite.png

Design Suite also lets you control the layout of your form with different column configurations and orientations.